# Why does the "question edited" notification redirect to the Desktop website even when on mobile?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, notifications

I have recently noticed that, on the mobile version of rpg.stackexchange, all notifications (red or green) redirect to the appropriate mobile page... except for the "question edited" notification (which, when clicked, redirects to the Desktop version, which of course displays in a weird way on mobile).

Why is it so? Is it a bug or an intended behavior?

Comment: I've marked this as "by design" since it's how the site works by intention, but I'll also note that [TeamDAG has been working on a responsive design for the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305561/152515) which means pages like that one may become mobile-friendly sometime this year.

Answer (score 5):

There is no mobile version of that page.

There's a lot of site functionality that doesn't have mobile versions. This isn't the most commonly used page, so it's not really a big deal.

Comment: Should there be ?

Comment: There's a lot of site functionality that doesn't have mobile versions. This isn't the most commonly used page, so it's not really a big deal.

Comment: Fair enough ! So it's a known issue without a very big impact.